# Amazon EC2 and EBS disk space error?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

This is the results, df show /mnt used 381G, but du show only 57G. Any one know how this happend?

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              15G  8.1G  6.0G  58% /
none                  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdc              414G  381G   13G  97% /mnt

du -smh /mnt
57G /mnt

du -smh /
74G /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes open file descriptors can cause the outputs to differ. Try:

```
lsof | grep tmp
```

to see if there's any such files.

Comment: Can that take more than 300G?

Comment: Technically, yes. What is your output? df calculates by looking at the inode table and processes locking huge swap files would cause the difference. The command might be lsof +L1 thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running du as root. Some directories may be restricted